# How to print MLB data into Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

I am still learning how to web scrape and could use some help. I would like to print the MLB data into a Pandas DataFrame.

It looks like the program does not run correctly but I did not receive an error. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help that you may offer.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/data/war_daily_bat.txt'
headers = {'User-Agent':
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

df = pd.read_html(url)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page contains a text file in CSV format. So load it with pandas like this:

```
    pd.read_csv(url)
```

And that should get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any scraping to accomplish this because the content is already in a csv-readable format.

Therefore you can put the data into the data frame with `read_csv`. Pandas also supports other formats such as `json` and `excel` (`read_json`, `read_excel` respectively).

If you would like to test for sure you can run:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://www.baseball-reference.com/data/war_daily_bat.txt')

print(f'Head of the Data\n{df.head()}')
print(f'Data contains {df.shape[0]} rows and {df.shape[1]} columns')
```

This will print out the first rows of data and the number of rows and columns in the data.